# How to write an email for politely asking an schedule of 2nd round of interview

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, reinterviewing

I attended an interview on the 16th April 2016. I was informed that I was shortlisted for the second round of interviews. 15 days back I got an email saying that HR has not received any tentative schedule for an arrival from US, who will be taking the 2nd round of interviews and was told they will be updating me soon regarding the schedule and the interviewer details. But it's been 2 weeks; and still I got no schedule for the interview. Please let me know how to follow up and write an effective email to ask for the schedule.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi XX,
>
> I am writing to ask whether there are any updates on when the second
>   interview will take place. I am very interested in the position and
>   would love to move forward with your company.
>
> Thanks for your time.
>
> Sincerely, Altaf.

Key points:

1. Keep things short and direct.
2. Don't appear pushy or impatient.
3. Reiterate your interest.

Move on if you still don't hear from them. Ignoring you is very unprofessional.

Meanwhile, keep yourself busy by looking for other jobs as well. Keep your options open; don't pin all your hopes on one company. If you end up receiving multiple offers, your negotiating power will improve.